# cppcheck issue publishing results

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cppcheck, jenkins-cli

I face the below issue at the end of analysis while running the cppcheck for my code..

```
 '/tmp/workspace/project'.  Did you enter a pattern relative to the correct directory?  Did you   generate the XML report(s) for Cppcheck?
```

[Cppcheck] Parsing throws exceptions. No cppcheck test report file(s) were found with the pattern  n   'report.xml' relative to '/tmp/workspace/project'.  Did you enter a pattern relative to the correct directory?  Did you generate the XML report(s) for Cppcheck?

I am currently running the below command.

```
cppcheck /Projects/Source -i boost/ -i sal/ -i nss/ -i moz/ --xml-version=2 --enable=all > /projects/Source/report.xml
```

Has anyone faced a similar error.. the analysis is successful though.. i am running the build on the jenkins.

Comment: I did not copy the xml file once its generated back to the workspace where the plugin was looking in the cpp check configuration.. once it was done i was able to publish my results..

Comment: I've voted to close this as it appears it was a simple user error causing your problem, and not a problem with the command you were running.